# Angular reactive forms two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to build an Angular reactive form in which inputs field values are updated based on inputs in other fields. Three input fields `amount`, `price` and `total` are supposed to reflect changes so that `amount * price = total` holds. Full code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7rnxf

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="orderForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">  
    Amount: <input (keyup)="onAmountChange($event)" formControlName="amount">{{ orderForm.value.amount }}<br>
    Price: <input (keyup)="onPriceChange($event)" formControlName="price">{{ orderForm.value.price }}<br>
    Total: <input (keyup)="onTotalChange($event)" formControlName="total"> {{ orderForm.value.total }}<br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  orderForm = this.fb.group({
    amount: 200,
    price: 95,
    total: ''
  });
  onTotalChange(e) {
    const total = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.orderForm.value.amount = total / this.orderForm.value.price;
  }
  onAmountChange(e) {
    const amount = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.orderForm.value.total = this.orderForm.value.amount * this.orderForm.value.price;
  }
  onPriceChange(e) {
    const price = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.orderForm.value.total = price * this.orderForm.value.amount;
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.orderForm.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: this.orderForm.value is read only thats why you can not overwrite

Comment: instead of all the `(keyup)`s, simply subscribe to `this.orderForm.valueChanges`. It's a good idea to read at least the documentation's first page

Comment: That's a statement of fact, not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.orderForm.value` is read only. then you can Try by doing something like  this

```
this.orderForm.controls['total'].setValue(price/ this.orderForm.value.amount);
```

[stackblitz example modified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dewwe?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Im unsure how to fork stackblitz but if you replace your class with the following you will get the correct result.

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  public orderForm: FormGroup;

  public ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
      amount: 200,
      price: 95,
      total: ''
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const amount = this.orderForm.controls.amount.value;
    const price = this.orderForm.controls.price.value;

    this.orderForm.controls.total.setValue(amount * price);
  }
}
```

This will give you the total on submit, to have the value changing as the other inputs do, you could re add the functions as they were but now instead looking to use `this.orderForm`. When ever a change is made to one of the input fields, you can check its value with `this.orderForm.controls.price.value` or `this.orderForm.controls.price.value`. Or you could just `console.log(this.orderForm.value);` to get all three values as an object. Which would look like `{amount: 200, price: "97", total: 19400}`.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the above answers offer the solutions of using [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue), which is more than enough, in this given scenario. However, I would like you to know that you can make use of [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchvalue) too.

For instance, if you would like to only update the value of `total` (and not other  FormControls) on your reactive form, you can simply achieve that by doing this:

```
this.orderForm.patchValue({
  total: price * this.amount
});
```

As you can see, the syntax is simpler and much more intuitive. On the other hand, if you try to achieve that with setValue, you will have to explicitly chain it, or 
you have to update all the FormControls due to the limitations of `setValue` and the way that method works. If you do not supply all the FormControls, it will throw an error. This may not be a bad thing, as it is 'safer'.

```
this.orderForm.setValue({
  amount: 200,
  price: 95,
  total: price * this.amount
})
```